# PHPMyAdmin Designer does not show relations

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

When using the PHPMyAdmin Designer tool I can not see relations (lines that connect each foreign key relation). The foreign key attributes get a different icon than the other attributes, however the line connection is missing. I already tried switching on/off "Show/Hide relations". [image: PHPMyAdmin Designer]

What am I missing?

Comment: BTW: Using German table and column names is such a bad design. I'm German, too, but when it come to programming, you should speak English.

Comment: It's not my convention. This is part of my final examination in computer science, I hate it myself. However, this is typically for German exams, always away from practice...

Comment: What browser are you using? What phpMyAdmin version?

Comment: Hi did you manage to fix this?

Comment: @utev Unfortunately, no.

Answer (score 7):

Click `Toggle Relationship lines`, and then line of relationship will be visible:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need to correct the internal table relationships and then the lines appear.

(Select each table > structure view > relations view > internal relationships > change what is wrong)

I've got a portuguese install so the names might be slightly different. I did this and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

I have read that you have to have innodb type tables, though I cannot get this to work myself even with an database of all innodb tables. The foreign keys are tagged but the relation lines will not display....
You are supposed to have "relation view" enabled (check structure tab to see if you have "relation view" avaiable for each table), but for me it makes no difference. Frustrating!

Edit: I have set up pma user, configured privileges. No warnings for configuration storage setup - configured as per definition of phpmyadmin wiki. Imported several databases. No visual relations in Designer! Foreign keys are imported but the connectors are not there in Designer.

Answer (score 1):

Right click and select toggle relation lines

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue was reported [here](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/12160), and the solution is explained (quite cryptically) [here](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#manual-configuration).

You have to import a script in your database that will enable certain features, among which there the capability to establish relationships between tables.

1. First, locate the script stored in *phpMyAdmin-installation-dir/sql*. It would usually be `create_tables.sql`, though it may be any of the others under the same directory, depending on whether you've migrated from a previous phpMyAdmin version or not. You can read about int in the second link I provided.
2. Open phpMyAdmin and click on your database name.
3. Choose *Import* and open the proper script.
4. When the import is over, you'll see there is a new batch of tables within your database. The existence of this tables enables a set of features in your database.

Now, if you select any table, you'll be able to select *Structure* > *Relation view* on top. Click on it and you'll be able to establish foreing key constraints.

Else, open Designer and you'll be able to use the graphical tool to create constraints and also see the ones you define using the *Relation view* option.