# The relationship lines are not showing in xampp's phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

The relationship lines in the designer view in phpmyadmin are not showing. I have 2 elements, one has a primary key and the other has an index. When I am trying to connect the two to create a relationship, a line should be drawn between them and a box asking for what should happen on deletion and on update should appear, but neither of these happens.

This problem appeared when I deleted an older version of XAMPP and downloaded the latest one. It seems that it is different working with this version than the older one.

#### I have tried the all the solutions suggested for similar problems. But none of them worked for me.

### I tried:

1. the **pma_designer_settings** value is: ({"angular_direct":"direct","snap_to_grid":"off","relation_lines":"true","small_big_all":">","full_screen":"off","side_menu":"false"})
2. I tried clicking the toggle relationship lines in the designer page
3. One of the rows is a primary key and the other is index
4. All the tables storage engine are InnoDB

Comment: as PHPMyAdmin is a browser based tool try a other browser?

Comment: Have you tried this Stackoverflow post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31401201/phpmyadmin-designer-does-not-show-relations/31643892

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the problem. Instead of using the relationship lines, I clicked on **Structure** and then **Relation View** and simply, I could select the details of my relation and I needed no more the relation lines.