# Amazon Linux 2 and MySQL phpMyAdmin Designer wiath all available updates does not show relations

Tags: amazon-web-services, phpmyadmin

I have a sample CUSTOMERS-ORDERS database in my phpMyAdmin. I tried to create relations in Designer, but the designer does not allow create them. I found one solution and I tried it. It does work.

[PHPMyAdmin Designer does not show relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31401201/phpmyadmin-designer-does-not-show-relations)

I run the create_tables.sql script. It helped me that I was able to create a relation between CUSTOMER and ORDER tables, but the relation lines are not showing in Designer. If I try recreate relation, Designer says that there are already existing relation …(or something like that).

By pressing Toggle relationship lines in the designer does not help.

I am sure that there are relation between these two tables but lines are not showing.

I'm using AWS, newest Amazon Linux 2 AMI, with all available updates, the newest PHP and MySQL with all updates.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: what engine are you using?

Comment: I am using InnoDB

Comment: I rolled back to version 4.9.0.1 of phpMyAdmin and now the designer shows the lines correctly between CUSTOMER and ORDER tables.