# How to show relationships lines in phpMyAdmin Designer of a database tables created using Laravel php artisan migrate command

Tags: phpmyadmin

After I migrated the database from a Laravel project using php artisan migrate I used the phpMyAdmin Designer tab to display the database design, but the relationships lines was missing. toggling the relationship lines didn't help. How can I solve this problem? (notice: all my databases created using Laravel migration have the same problem, other databases shows the relationship lines normally) Any help would be greatly appreciated. [See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuQhI.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHPMyAdmin Designer does not show relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31401201/phpmyadmin-designer-does-not-show-relations)

Comment: Unfortunately, no.